# Detect whether Apple Pencil is connected to an iPad Pro

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Is there an API that allows you to determine whether the Apple Pencil is connected to an iPad Pro? Looking over the 9.1 SDK I don't see anything that directly does this. Or perhaps this can be done using the Bluetooth API.

Comment: Did you find anything in the Bluetooth API for this?

Comment: @rich I believe that the only thing you can do is scan the bluetooth devices. But you need BT permission for this. I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can't find any actual documentation on the Apple Pencil's Bluetooth 
implementation (and I don't believe any exists), but the following code Works 
for Me™.

It checks for connected devices that advertise themselves as supporting the 
"Device Information" service and then  if any of these have the name "Apple 
Pencil".

#### PencilDetector.h

```c
@import CoreBluetooth

@interface PencilDetector : NSObject <CBCentralManagerDelegate>

- (instancetype)init;

@end
```

#### PencilDetector.m

```c
#include "PencilDetector.h"

@interface PencilDetector ()

@end

@implementation PencilDetector
{
  CBCentralManager* m_centralManager;
}

- (instancetype)init
{
  self = [super init];
  if (self != nil) {
    // Save a reference to the central manager. Without doing this, we never get
    // the call to centralManagerDidUpdateState method.
    m_centralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self
                                                            queue:nil
                                                          options:nil];
  }

  return self;
}

- (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central
{
  if ([central state] == CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn)
  {
    // Device information UUID
    NSArray* myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"180A"]];

    NSArray* peripherals =
      [m_centralManager retrieveConnectedPeripheralsWithServices:myArray];
    for (CBPeripheral* peripheral in peripherals)
    {
        if ([[peripheral name] isEqualToString:@"Apple Pencil"])
        {
            // The Apple pencil is connected
        }
    }
  }
}

@end
```

In practice, the following, simpler, synchronous code, which doesn't wait for 
the central manager to be powered on before checking for connected devices 
seems to work just as well in my testing. However, the documentation states that you shouldn't 
call any methods on the manager until the state has updated to be 
`CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn`, so the longer code is probably safer.

#### Anywhere you like

```c
m_centralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:nil
                                                        queue:nil
                                                      options:nil];

// Device information UUID
NSArray* myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"180A"]];

NSArray* peripherals =
  [m_centralManager retrieveConnectedPeripheralsWithServices:myArray];
for (CBPeripheral* peripheral in peripherals)
{
  if ([[peripheral name] isEqualToString:@"Apple Pencil"])
  {
    // The Apple pencil is connected
  }
}
```

Comment: @combinatorial Whoops! Can you tell it's been a while since I've written much Objective-C? *ahem*. Thanks for the edit!

Comment: What is @"180A"? is it fixed?

Comment: @ChandanShettySP @"180A" is an NSString corresponding to the the hex value `0x180A`, which is the Bluetooth "Assigned Number" or "short UUID" for the "Device Information" service. This is a service that the current Pencil device offers, and it should continue to work in the future as most (or possibly all) Bluetooth devices should offer this service.

Comment: this code is not working if you turn off bluetooth from control center on ios 11 and later, the CBCentralManager will have CBManagerStatePoweredOff state

Comment: Hmmm - this works only if the device is connected. If separated from the iPad for some time, it loses the connection. In that case, we may want to scan all Bluetooth devices, and this would not work.

Answer (score 6):

Took me quite a while to figure out that CBCentralManager's `centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral)` is only called when the connection is initiated via its `connect(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, options: [String : Any]? = nil)` function (yes, reading the docs helps :]).

Since we have no callback for when devices have been connected to the device through the user (as is the case with Apple Pencil - I'd love to be proven wrong on this one btw), I had to resort to using a timer here.

This is how it works:

When you initialize `ApplePencilReachability` a timer is setup that checks for the availability of the pencil every second. If a pencil is found the timer gets invalidated, if bluetooth is turned off it also gets invalidated. When it's turned on again a new timer is created.

I am not particularly proud of it but it works :-)

```
import CoreBluetooth

class ApplePencilReachability: NSObject, CBCentralManagerDelegate {

  private let centralManager = CBCentralManager()
  var pencilAvailabilityDidChangeClosure: ((_ isAvailable: Bool) -> Void)?

  var timer: Timer? {
    didSet {
      if oldValue !== timer { oldValue?.invalidate() }
    }
  }

  var isPencilAvailable = false {
    didSet { 
      guard oldValue != isPencilAvailable else { return }
      pencilAvailabilityDidChangeClosure?(isPencilAvailable)
    }
  }

  override init() {
    super.init()
    centralManager.delegate = self
    centralManagerDidUpdateState(centralManager) // can be powered-on already?
  }
  deinit { timer?.invalidate() }

  func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
    if central.state == .poweredOn {
      timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { 
        [weak self] timer in // break retain-cycle
        self?.checkAvailability()
        if self == nil { timer.invalidate() }
      }
    } else {
      timer = nil
      isPencilAvailable = false
    }
  }

  private func checkAvailability() {
    let peripherals = centralManager.retrieveConnectedPeripherals(withServices: [CBUUID(string: "180A")])
    let oldPencilAvailability = isPencilAvailable
    isPencilAvailable = peripherals.contains(where: { $0.name == "Apple Pencil" })
    if isPencilAvailable {
      timer = nil // only if you want to stop once detected
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Admit it! You just copied the code from over here!!! ;-): https://gitlab.com/DanielBocksteger/BOApplePencilReachability/blob/master/BOApplePencilReachability.swift

Comment: Well, that file has a copyright from 2017 so it’s probably the other way around, but nice find, I actually know Daniel :D

Comment: You should probably not compare the peripheral by name, but by looking at a pencil specific service (UUID). You can use the Xcode Bluetooth tools to browse the services provided.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer @hnh , I don’t have the time currently to look at it, but I’ll write it on my todo list :) (of you already have a solution please feel free to edit the code :))

Comment: Hey cool @hnh, thanks for your edit :) Looks really good, especially the weak capturing, dunno how I missed that ... The only thing I currently don't understand is why we only invalidate the timer when we set it to nil and not when we set it to a new timer ... Maybe I have to get some sleep before ;) Anyways, thank you very much 

Comment: You are right. Also, FWIW, all the BT stuff should probably run on a background queue (it could DispatchQueue.main.async the callback). And again, the name comparison is likely a bad idea.

Comment: Good points, again thanks for making the answer better :) +2 (elsewhere )

Comment: In iOS 13 and newer there's a `CBCentralManager.registerForConnectionEvents` so polling every second like this is not needed.