# Detect if an iPad can use an Apple Pencil (is iPad Pro)

Tags: ios, ipad

Is there a way to detect if the model of an iPad supports Apple Pencil?

I can check for the [UIDeviceHardware platformString] which returns the model of iPad and I can get the Pro models, but I would like a definitive solution that works even for future iPad Pro models.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37133248/how-to-differentiate-whether-a-user-is-tapping-the-screen-with-his-finger-or-an or maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32542250/detect-whether-apple-pencil-is-connected-to-an-ipad-pro?rq=1

Comment: Both probably not exactly what you want, but you can either detect if there is an Apple Pencil connected using this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41264961/1489885 or which device you’re running on using this: https://github.com/dennisweissmann/DeviceKit

Comment: The detection of a connected Apple Pencil doesn't work for me. Just need to know if the iPad has the capability.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if device supports 3D Touch with [forceTouchCapability](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitraitcollection/1623515-forcetouchcapability?language=objc) API, and additionally check if the device is an iPad with [userInterfaceIdiom](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice/1620037-userinterfaceidiom?language=objc). For now there is no API to detect 3D Touch availability with fingers for iPad or Apple Pencil for iPhone.

```
if (UIDevice.currentDevice.userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad &&
    UIScreen.mainScreen.traitCollection.forceTouchCapability == UIForceTouchCapabilityAvailable)
{
    // this device in current state supports stylus
}
```

Comment: The force touch capability always reports back `.unavailable` on an iPad in my testing.